# Regex to extract a number of any length from a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a number (Must exist, any length) from a string. The string should actually start with the number. I am using this expression:

```
[[\d]+YMD]
```

When given 11M as input, the 11 is matched twice as 1 then 1. What am I missing in this RegEx?

I am writing a web application, but for now, I am testing the RegEx [online](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) where I am getting the same results.

Comment: Try `^\d+` if you want to retrieve the number at the start of your string

Comment: I think you want `^\d+[YMD]`

Comment: Or else use a capturing group or lookahead `^\d+(?=[YMD])` to get the digits only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely looking for the + quantifier which: "Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed".

`^\d+(D|M|Y)` will specifically give you what you seem to be looking for (making it only match if it starts with a number and ends with `D`, `M`, or `Y`, making sure there's at least 1 number.

https://regex101.com/r/gWxkhd/2

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want:

```
^\d+
```

`^` = start of string
`\d` = any digit
`+` = 1 or more